# Frequency meter (counter)

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency, amplitude-modulation, frequency-measurement, digital-modulation

I am currently working on designing a circuit that should be able to measure the frequency of an input signal by giving off a value directly proportional to the frequency at the input.

The circuit should function with highly variable signals, with irregular shapes, amplitudes or duty cycles, and should have a bandwidth ranging from a few hertz (in my circuit, that value is around 10) to over 10 kHz. The idea is quite simple: use a comparator at the input (with hefty amount of speed and linearity) that has a threshold voltage varying in accordance to the signal at the input, transform the output into a logical signal and then run it through a circuit that makes it duty cycle independent (a universal width for each pulse).

Finally, run the resulting wave through a stage that delivers charge packages to a capacitor each time a new pulse arrives. The output DC voltage should be proportional to the number of pulses presented at the input (let's say that x is the voltage according to the time of one pulse. For 2 Hz the voltage is 2x). The input logical branch has gone off with a strong start.

[image]
***comparator stage***

The design is quite simple. U3 is the comparator responsible with slewing its output and thus creating an output square wave. Given that the application requires for the stage to face hearty irregular signals, the threshold voltage can't remain steady. U2 has the role of charging capacitor C1 through R1 (C3 adapting the RC time constant required for a given input frequency), pushing large currents through R1 if the amplitude varies widely. This way the voltage seen at the positive input of U3 is always proportional to the voltage seen at the input, but with a few volts behind.

U4 works on the same principle, its role being mainly for linearization of the logical output (it is needed due to op-amp imperfections).

The following stages are mainly comprised of integrators and an output comparator (again, for linearization), their role being that of taming the logical output for small frequency signals. C6 and C7 are again neccessary for bypassing at high frequencies. Don't care about U10 which is an inverting buffer, it being likely eliminated once I design the following stages.

Also, U6 is needed for isolating U2's input, which oscillates shortly at steep inputs due to settling time. I tested out the design on some random input signals, and as I will show the results it works very nice.

[image]
***The green trace is the input signal and the blue one is what the threshold voltage looks like at U3's input***

[image]
***This is an up close image, the red trace being the output signal seen at U10***

[image]
***Another example of a varying square wave***

[image]
***output signal***

[image]
***For diversity, a 10 Hz input signal with 1% duty cycle***

I tested tons of other signals and duty cycles, so the above pictures are just a part of it. The most error producing element in this circuit are the comparators from what I saw. I would like to replace them with some comparators that are faster and more accurate, or at least some fast op-amps configured as comparators (even undercompensated varieties, as long as they are not too unstable).

The [AD8030](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8029_8030_8040.pdf) op-amps I am using are quite good for signals above 10 Hz and lower than some 20 kHz. Below this range the op-amps go berserk, saturating without any apparent reason. In cases where I am using a square wave with frequencies below 10 Hz, it sometimes is the fault of the threshold generator, due to the fact that it's slew rate is intentionally limited (a feature without which the output becomes even more problematic). Sine waves work better due to their slower voltage variability, and closer resemblence to the RC time constant rising and falling wave. Even so, with slow sine waves the AD8030 becomes the problem, saturating even when the input differential voltage remains at a steady level. Also, the slow slew rate of this comparator makes the second stage comprised out of U5 and U4 neccessary. So better comparators also lower my component count.

The bandwidth is preferable at some 40 kHz-50 kHz, and perhaps if possible even lower than 10 Hz. Also they should be rail-to-rail or over-the-top varieties.

[image]
***output of U3 for an irregular input signal***

There are many other reasons why comparator imperfections lower the accuracy of my circuit, and I ask for advice regarding possible comparator choices for simulation in LTspice, but also in a real circuit.

Do note that I plan to build this thing, so this being said I also need some options for the input and output buffers. Here I used ideal op-amps. Any other recommendations regarding how the circuit can be improved are always welcome.

Also, please don't be too harsh as this is my first complex circuit. I am aware that there could be place for better, but I am really proud of how this first stage turned out.

Also, note that in the actual circuit I would add some hysteresis at the inputs, as this circuit is highly sensitive (so sensitive that I had to roll off its response through RC R1C1 and the like), I also consider using the configuration for a noise meter.

The circuit works just fine with these op-amps, but the performance could be largely improved with better specimens. Also, the input voltage range should be some 10 to -10 V.

Comment: please do not post a comment with additional  information ... edit your question instead ... delete the comment